# How do i trigger a lightbox when certain text is selected using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so i have this

```
<select class="something">

  <option value=''>
    Select a Project
  </option>
    ---
  </option>
  <option value="/projects/2">test</option>
  <option value="/projects/3">test2</option>
  <option value="/projects/4">test7</option>
  <option value="/projects/5">test5</option>
```

When someone clicks the Select a Project how would popup a lightbox just for that and not if they select the others....Popping up the lightbox is not too hard its distinquishing from the other options that i dont understand

```
$(".something").change
```

this will get all but i only want "Select a Project"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.something').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() == '') {
      // Your code here:
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
$(".something").bind("change", function(eventObj) {
    if($(":selected",this).text() === "Select a Project") {
        // open lightbox
    }
});
```

I like checking `.val()` in most cases, but if your value is an empty string...I feel iffy about it so I would check against the text of the selected option in this case.